# php include in wordpress template shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, shortcode

i'm working with a wordpress plugin to output a php include that depends on the country code, i've set up the conditional shortcodes that output text dependant on location, but can't take that to the next level to include a php file:

```
<? echo do_shortcode('[wpgc_is_country_code country_code="UK"]' . 'hello' .'[/wpgc_is_country_code]');?>
```

this outputs "hello", but i'd like it to inlcude a php file. i've tried this:

```
<? echo do_shortcode('[wpgc_is_country_code country_code="UK"]' . 'include('include/UK.php')' .'[/wpgc_is_country_code]');?>
```

but its not working, the output is blank, where am i going wrong in the "include" portion of things? (i've also tried using the "get_template_part" function with no luck)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

hello is a string so must have quote but include is a function , it is wrong to have any function in quote..remove single quote on the `include()`, and try this

```
<? echo do_shortcode('[wpgc_is_country_code country_code="UK"]' . include('include/UK.php') .'[/wpgc_is_country_code]');?>
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification about the quotes, the code is still not outputting anything for me. using the same include php without conditionals:

   <?php include('include/UK.php'); ?>

works fine and displays the php contents perfectly. so, baffled!